# What the original license ubuntu theme

Tags: themes

Hei All, I have search on google about the original license of Ubuntu theme but didn't found it for the example "Ambiance", yes you can got it on internet, but has modified an people release under deferent license, no author contact address etc in its folder. ok just, i need to edit it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every package the license is described in the file `/usr/share/doc/PACKAGENAME/copyright` (where `PACKAGENAME` is the name of the package.

Most of the files for the Ambiance theme are in the folder `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/`.
We can use `dpkg` to find the package that folder belongs to:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/themes/Ambiance
light-themes: /usr/share/themes/Ambiance
```

So the package is `light-themes` and the license is in `/usr/share/doc/light-themes/copyright`: It's basically `CC-BY-SA-3.0` with exceptions for trademarks, logos etc. There are some contact addresses, too.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this project](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-themes) I am not sure whether the themes are really part of it because I did not dive deep into it. this seems to be licensed under GNU GPL v3.

Answer (score 0):

To find the copyright license of ubuntu artwork you can simply go and see it yourself in your system. It's located in.

/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-artwork/copyright

Terminal way to get there

```
    cd /usr/share/doc/ubuntu-artwork/copyright
```